# Big drop in valid pages in GSC

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have a very small site with only about 70 pages.  About 4 days ago GSC shows a 40% drop in the valid of number indexed pages.  When I probe into which pages, it shows pages that I'm still ranking well for.

Is this something I should be concerned about?  Is this a bug in GSC or will these pages ultimately drop from Google search results?

Comment: Google Search Console is new and yes buggy, even there were such issues in older version as well. Before getting confused you should check if your pages are in index, when they got indexed and verify time of those validation issues. Keep watching your crawling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google recently had a glitch that caused lots of pages to get de-indexed. This has been fixed. You are now seeing the delayed report on that de-indexing. In a few days you should see it recover.

Comment: Thanks Tony.  The numbers are back corrected today.